# Determine the convergence of the following series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to determine the convergence of the following series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}}$

At first, when i saw this series i thought that it is alternating, since function $\sin x$ is sometimes above, sometimes under the $x$ axis. But then, when a took a better look at the argument i noticed that in this case, sine remains in the first quadrant since when $n=1 \Rightarrow \sin\frac{\pi}{2} = 1$ and after that, it just decreases to the point when we are looking for the sine of zero (when $n \rightarrow \infty)$, so it looks to me like it's going to converge, i just don't know how to prove that. I tried few tests, but none of them works, for example, when i try d'Alembert's test, i get $1$ which is undefined. So i am not really sure what to do with this.

Answer (score 5):

Always use asymptotic bounds to understand the terms.

Let "$[r]$" denote "$\{ x : |x| < |r| \}$" for any real $r$.

As $n \to \infty$:

$\sin(\frac{π}{2\sqrt{n}}) \in \frac{π}{2\sqrt{n}} + [\frac{π}{2\sqrt{n}}^3] = \frac{π}{2\sqrt{n}} + [\frac{π^3}{8n\sqrt{n}}]$ by Taylor expansion.

Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^m \sin(\frac{π}{2\sqrt{n}}) \in \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{π}{2\sqrt{n}} + \left[ \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{π^3}{8n\sqrt{n}} \right]$ by triangle inequality.

Now it should be clear what happens, because there is a $c$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{π^3}{8n\sqrt{n}}$ is bounded by $c$ for all $m$, and so it suffices to determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{π}{2\sqrt{n}}$ converges as $m \to \infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\sin \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for all $n$, so the series diverges by comparison.

In general, if you have a series $\sum \sin(a_n)$ where $a_n \to 0$, you should always be able to determine convergence by comparing it to $\sum a_n$ or some constant multiple of $\sum a_n$.

Answer (score 2):

We have that (the easiest approach I know to the following inequalities uses the fact that $\sin$ is concave in the given interval) $$\frac{2}{\pi}x\leq\sin(x)\leq x\quad\text{ for }x \in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right],$$

so

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\pi}{2n}
  &\leq&\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}}
  &\leq&\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}}
  &\leq&\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}}\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow&&&&\downarrow\\
\infty&&\infty&&&&\infty\\
\text{(harmonic series)}
\end{array}
and the sum diverges (actually, as the lower bound is $\infty$, the upper bound is not necessary).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain me why is it divergent, i mean if you read my question, you will see why i thought this is convergent, i mean, when we start with $n=1$ we have that the first term is $1$ every next term is positive, so it increases the value of sum, but every next term has lower value than the previous one, until the point when $n\rightarrow \infty$, shouldn't then this sum converge?

Comment: @cdummie I've added one more sum on the left side: observe that $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, yet the harmonic sum still diverges.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed this is a positive series so you can use any of the powerful tests for positive series, say limit comparison limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\frac\pi{2\sqrt n}}{\frac\pi{2\sqrt n}}=1\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac\pi{2\sqrt n}=0\implies\;\text{since}\;\;\sum_{n=1}\frac\pi{2\sqrt n}$$

diverges, then also our series diverges.